# Packaging and Deploying page layouts with VS and Management Shell

Tags: powershell, page-layout, solution-deployment

I have created a .wsp file through Visual Studio which should contain a module with my page layouts I want to deploy.  To do this I downloaded my page layout .aspx that was already created on my development environment site and stuck it in my PageLayouts module in VS (I also renamed it to .layout because I read somewhere SharePoint messes with .aspx files).  I made sure the module is included in my feature and that the feature is scoped to Site, then published my .wsp file.

Then, over in my test environment, I copied the .wsp to C:\Deploy\Page_Layouts.wsp and ran the following command:

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath C:\Deploy\Page_Layouts.wsp
```

Usually I would also run (for webparts):

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity Page_Layouts.wsp -AllWebApplications -GACDeployment -Force
```

but this gave me an error that the solution contains no resources scoped for a Web application and cannot be deployed to a particular Web application.  I'm not sure if it should be like that or not but at any rate I would expect to see my page layout in the master page gallery if this worked correctly.

If I try to deploy to my development environment directly through VS I get the following Error:

"Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Value does not fall within the expected range."

This is what my module currently looks like in Elements.xml in case anything in there could be causing it:

```
<Module Name="PageLayouts">
  <File Path="PageLayouts\Three Columns Custom.layout" Url="/_catalogs/masterpage">
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;"/>
      <Property Name="PublishingAssociatedContentType" Value=";#Article Page;#0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D;#" />
      <Property Name="Title" Value="Three Columns Custom" />
      <Property Name="MasterPageDescription" Value="Three column layout" />
  </File>
</Module>
```

Comment: Try removing the -AllWebApplications switch in your command

Comment: Surprisingly that worked.  I thought Install-SPSolution always needed a target (either -AllWebApplications or -WebApplication and specifying a site).  So now I can get it to show up in my Site Collection Features but when I try to activate it it says "The URL /_catalogs/masterpage is invalid".  If I try it with "_catalogs/masterpage" it tells me the specified list does not exist.  I've also tried an absolute path and that doesn't work either :(

Comment: Got it!  That Url attribute needed to be on the <Module> tag, not the <File> tag.  Between changing that and removing -AllWebApplications from the Powershell command it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page Layouts should NOT be deployed in the SharePoint mapped folder Layouts, which actualy maps to _layouts virtual folder.

Page layouts must be deployed in the masterpage catalog under */_catalogs/masterpage* (see here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobgerman/archive/2011/01/31/packaging-master-pages-and-page-layouts-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx and http://historiesofsharepointlover.wordpress.com/2011/12/31/deploying-pages-layouts-using-features-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: I've also tried this approach of making a module with the layout and setting the url attribute of the File element in Elements.xml to "/_catalogs/masterpage".  The feature is scoped to Site yet I keep getting that error with the Install-SPSolution call.  Nothing seems to say what the Powershell commands should be because they just say "Hit deploy in VS"; unfortunately I don't have this convenience because my VS points to my development environment but I want to deploy to my test environment.  Could I just be using a wrong command?

Comment: My question is updated to better reflect the current situation now.